# Story about a man who's exploring an alien construction on the moon. He must die repeatedly before he gets to the end

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It may have been an alien-built installation or spaceship. I just
remember that it was fantastically dangerous inside.

It was at least 30 years ago. I don't remember where I read this story, but it was probably in an anthology. I thought it might have been in one of the *Science Fiction Hall of Fame* anthologies, but I've reread them and haven't run across it.

As I recall it, the explorer volunteered for the job. He goes a short distance and then dies. The researchers outside make a map of his progress. Somehow they bring him back to life, but at the end when he's done there are two of him. What will they do?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it a full novel or a short story?  Can you remember any of the ways in which he dies?  Is he alone?  Why is he doing this?  What's at "the end?"

Comment: Thanks for the assist! It was at least 30 years ago. I thought it might have been in one of the Science Fiction Hall of Fame anthologies, but I've reread them and haven't run across it. As I recall it, the explorer volunteered for the job. He goes a short distance and then dies. The researchers outside make a map of his progress. Somehow they bring him back to life, but at the end when he's done there are two of him. What will they do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you say the explorer is reanimated and sent back it sounds like it might be "[Rogue Moon](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56691)" (1960) by Algis Budrys; it was included in the anthology [*The Science Fiction Hall of Fame, Volume Two*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?29111).  (It was also expanded into a [novel with the same title](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1285), but that doesn't seem like what you're describing.)

From the plot summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_Moon#Synopsis):

> Dr. Edward Hawks runs a top-secret project for the United States Navy investigating a large alien artifact found on the Moon. Hawks has created a matter transmitter which scans a person or object to make a copy at receivers on the Moon. The earthbound person is placed in a state of sensory deprivation which allows him to share the experiences of his doppelgänger. The copies enter and explore the alien labyrinth, but are killed for violating the unknown rules in force within the structure. Each explorer gets a little further and learns a bit more about what they can and cannot do.

And at the end the duplicates have to remain on the Moon:

> Hawks tells Barker that they cannot return to Earth. The equipment on the Moon is too crude to transmit a man back safely, and even if it were possible, there are already people living their lives.

Comment: That was fast, and THANKS! It's exactly the story I wanted. Can't imagine how I missed it except that I may have nodded off while listening to the audiobook.